# "Smooth" Serre Fibrations (?)

Tags: homotopy-theory, smooth-manifolds, manifolds, fibration

Let $M,N$ be manifolds, $f:M \to N$ be a map. 
In order to understand if $f$ is a serre fibration, it is enough to test it against differntiable maps $I^p \to M, I^{p+1} \to N$? What about smooth maps? What about smooth embeddings?

This came to my mind because serre fibration is meant to be an homotopical property, and it seems unreasonable that homotopical property of manifolds can't be controlled by smooth maps. A starting point would be to show that every map between manifolds is homotopical to a smooth one.

Thanks, Andrea

Edit: for the last sentence, it probably comes from the simplicial approximation plus the fact that every continous function $\Delta^n \to \Delta^n$ that is linear on the boundary can be "linearized" up to homotopy relative to the boundary.

Comment: That every map between manifolds is homotopic to a smooth one is a standard fact proved in almost every differential topology textbook. The standard proof is as follows: embed $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^D$ for some big $D$, approximate the maps $M→\mathbb{R}^D$ via smooth maps so that they fall in a tubular neighborhood and project a straight-line homotopy back to $N$.

Comment: So suppose that $H: M \times I \to N$ is the homotopy relating the smooth approximation with the original one. Is it true with this proof that $H$ is smooth in the interior of $M \times I$, namely $M \times (0,1)$?